# Mouse event listeners not working after 'dragstart' is fired in Javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, addeventlistener, draggable

I am currently developing a drag and drop interface and would like to implement a feature that allows users to return a dragged object to its original position by right-clicking.

In the demo below, the blue ball can be dragged to any of the 3 boxes. I added an event listener for a right-click mouseup event.

**Desired outcome:**

Anytime when I am dragging the ball, a right mouse click will end the drag event and return the ball to the original square it was dragged from.

**Actual outcome:**

When I am dragging the ball, a right mouse click does nothing. Only after I drop the ball does a right-click return the ball to the original square.

**Potential problem identified**

After testing, this issue may be due to the fact that additional mouse event listeners are not active during the 'dragging' phase. What should I do?

**Code**

```js
const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
const ball = document.getElementById("ball");

for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  boxes[i].addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
  boxes[i].addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.appendChild(ball);
  });
}

var originalBox;
ball.setAttribute("draggable", true);
ball.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
  originalBox = ball.closest(".box");
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
  // (event.button === 2) checks if the right mouse button was clicked
  if (event.button === 2) {
    originalBox.appendChild(ball);
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#ball {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id="ball"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to problem solve is to use a flag variable to keep track of ball is being dragged or not.

When the right-click event is triggered, you can check the flag variable to determine the ball is currently dragged, and if So, you can return it to the original box.

Try this code.

```js
const boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
const ball = document.getElementById("ball");
let originalBox;
let isDragging = false;
let dragStartX;
let dragStartY;

for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  boxes[i].addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
  boxes[i].addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.appendChild(ball);
  });
}

ball.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  originalBox.appendChild(ball);
});

ball.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  if (event.button === 2) {
    // Right mouse button clicked
    originalBox = ball.closest(".box");
    isDragging = true;
    dragStartX = event.clientX;
    dragStartY = event.clientY;
  }
});

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  if (isDragging) {
    const deltaX = event.clientX - dragStartX;
    const deltaY = event.clientY - dragStartY;
    ball.style.transform = `translate(${deltaX}px, ${deltaY}px)`;
  }
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
  if (isDragging) {
    isDragging = false;
    ball.style.transform = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#ball {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div id="ball"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your proposed solution, but it doesn't work for me when I am testing it. I would like to return the blue ball to the original position anytime when I right-click when I am dragging it. However, in your snippet, when I am dragging the blue ball and try to right-click, nothing happens. In fact nothing happens when I right-click after I let go of the ball as well.

Comment: Sorry @alph.  we edit my snipped can you try again.

Comment: @M Surya, no problem, thanks for helping me. Sorry, but your code doesn't work. I tested it by 1. Starting the drag event 2. Right-clicking during the drag event. Expected step 3: After steps 1 and 2, the drag even should end and the ball should go back to its original square. Actual result from your snippet: Now, I don't see the ghost image of the ball while dragging, and when right-clicking, the ball just sort of follows my mouse around a bit. I don't want the right click to move the ball, I want it to return to the original square. Thanks.